# Escoger valor por defecto en SelectOneMenu

Tags: java, html, jsf, xhtml

tengo un pequeño problema, cuando inicio la aplicación, por defecto tengo seleccionado lo que esta dentro del SelectItem, pero me gustaría en vez de tener eso, tener seleccionado un componente del combo de SelectItems, es posible? Un saludo

El codigo:

```
           <div class="row group">
                    <h:outputLabel for="critEjec" value="#{msg['cod_ejec']}" styleClass="nombreCampo"/>  
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="critEjec" value="#{maestroSubCategoriasBean.critEjec}" styleClass="campo">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['comunes_seleccionarTodos']}" itemValue="-1" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.comboListaEjesCatalogacion}" />
                        <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{maestroSubCategoriasController.llenarComboCategorias}" reRender="CategoriasPanel,mensajesPanel" ajaxSingle="true" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>  
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La opcion que quieras que muestre debe de venir en el value del selectOneMenu, en este caso tienes que asignarle el valor desde el bean.